# Exception while parsing 7z files in java/scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons, java-io

I have written a scala code to parse 7z files. I am using the org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile to parse it. The code seems to be written fine. Below is the code snippet of parsing the 7z files.

```
else if(file.endsWith("7z")) {
          val archiveFile:SevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(file));
          val contentBytes:ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          val entry = archiveFile.getNextEntry
          if(entry != null) {
            println("7z file in process: " + entry.getName);
            if(entry.isDirectory()) {
            println("Found directory entry: " + entry.getName);
          }
          else {
              val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024);
              while(archiveFile.read(buffer) != -1) {
              contentBytes.write(buffer, 0, archiveFile.read(buffer));
              //println(contentBytes.toString());
              arrayBufferValues += contentBytes.toString();
          }
          println("Done with processing file ====>>>>> " + Paths.get(file).getFileName + " ---- " + entry.getName);
          parseFilesMap.put(Paths.get(file).getFileName + "^" + entry.getName, arrayBufferValues)
          arrayBufferValues.clear();
}
```

And I am getting the below exception

```
java.io.IOException: kDummy is unsupported, please report
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readFilesInfo(SevenZFile.java:710)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readHeader(SevenZFile.java:241)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readHeaders(SevenZFile.java:197)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:116)
at Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:50)
at Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:25)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at Main$.main(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala:25)
at Main.main(TestFileProcessZip7z.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:175)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:161)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:161)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:129)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:129)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.trackingThreads(package.scala:43)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:27)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:128)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:192)
at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:205)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:67)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

What is the reason and how do I resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: And which line of the script triggers the exception? What is kDummy? We don't have a crystal ball to answer questions.

Comment: What version of commons compress are you using? It looks like kDummy has been [supported (ignored) for a while](https://github.com/apache/commons-compress/commit/7e6c7136cf0165f107daf8f9f1818c7d9c9fcc27#diff-703eef8bb98fd2435fe20e86cf3b51b4).

Comment: I am using commons-io-2.6.jar

Comment: Another weird thing is when I run it on my local I receive: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while on the server I receive the above mentioned exception

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at commons.apache.org, compress and io are separate projects and the `SevenZFile` class comes from compress. Not sure how you're managing your dependencies or anything, but using the latest version of commons compress should fix the kDummy error.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible that the environment has something to do with it, given the fact that I am using the latest version commons compress.

Comment: Are you positive? My logic is pretty much that if you look at the linked diff I posted above it shows that the exception you're receiving was removed in a 2014 commit that was incorporated into 1.9 ([see this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS-287)), so it seems to me that it's not even possible to get this exception in compress 1.9+. I don't know what else it could be so hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: I completely agree with you, even I am wondering how come I am getting this exception. I am running my code as sudo /opt/scala/bin/scala -classpath ".:/xxxx/xxxx/commons-compress-1.6.jar:/xxxx/xxxx/commons-io-2.6.jar:/xxxx/xxxx/xz-1.8.jar" TestFileProcessZip7z.scala. I am passing all the required dependencies, hope I am not missing anything here.

Comment: Finally I got the reason, commons-compress had version 1.6 while the latest version is 1.16.1. My bad :(

Comment: No worries, glad that fixed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

This exception caused because files zipped via 7zip using bzip2 compression.